# Is there a way to split shift records by date / time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have roster data that has night shift records (eg has start time of 2019-01-30 21:00:00.000  and a finish time of 2019-01-31 05:30:00.000 the following day.

I need to split this into 2 rows as follows

> 2019-01-30 21:00:00.000 to 2019-01-30 23:59:59.999
>
> 2019-01-31 00:00:00.001 to 2019-01-31 05:30:00.000

I need to  retain all other info from the line. and the day date is the date the shift started.

```
    SELECT  actual_id
            , emp_id
            , emp_number
            , area
            , area_id
            , day_date
            , start_time
            , finish_time

    FROM Roster
WHERE CONVERT(date,start_time, 112) <> CONVERT(date,finish_time, 112)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your sample desired output?

Comment: Are you doing this just because you are unable to handle dates across midnight boundary?

Comment: @Lucas : I have prepared query and I hope it will 100% works for you and also you have asked a good question so I am upvoting your question.

Answer (score 0):

To create two rows you can `CROSS JOIN` with a temp table having two rows like following.

```
select *
FROM roster 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                  SELECT 1 temp 
                  UNION 
                  SELECT 2 temp )t 
    ON  1=1
```

Above query will replicate each row two times.

Now based on the row number (1 or 2) you can get the end time of a day and start time of a day like

```
 CASE  WHEN t.rownum =1 THEN start_time 
        ELSE dateadd(second, 1, Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, finish_time), 0) 
       end starttime , 
 CASE 
     WHEN t.rownum=2 THEN finish_time 
        ELSE dateadd(ms, -2, dateadd(dd, 1, datediff(dd, 0, start_time))) 
     END AS endtime FROM roster
```

Your final query should look like following query.

```
SELECT     actual_id , 
           emp_id , 
           emp_number , 
           area , 
           area_id , 
           day_date , 
           CASE 
                      WHEN t.rownum=1 THEN start_time 
                      ELSE dateadd(second, 1, Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, finish_time), 0) 
           end starttime , 
           CASE 
                      WHEN t.rownum=2 THEN finish_time 
                      ELSE dateadd(ms, -2, dateadd(dd, 1, datediff(dd, 0, start_time))) 
           END AS endtime FROM roster 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                  SELECT 1 rownum
                  UNION 
                  SELECT 2 rownum)t 
    ON  1=1 
WHERE CONVERT(date,start_time, 112) <> CONVERT(date,finish_time, 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the mentioned solution:

```
SELECT
  s.emp_id,
  f.theDay
FROM Roster AS s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, Number, s.start_time)
FROM master..spt_values AS v
WHERE v.Type = 'P'
AND v.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, s.start_time, s.finish_time)) AS f (theDay)
ORDER BY s.emp_id,
f.theDay
```